# PHP interfering with Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, advanced-custom-fields

The PHP code seems to be blocking or interfering with my advanced custom fields as it doesn't display unless I remove the PHP code then it does. I can't figure out where the issue is.

Any help is much appreciated.

PHP

```
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'gaeilge') !== false) {

             $newsCat = 'cat=5,7&showposts=3';
    } else {
             $newsCat = 'cat=6,8&showposts=3';
         }; ?>
```

Advanced Custom Fields

```
  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row py-5">

                        <?php if( have_rows('block') ): ?>

                <?php while( have_rows('block') ): the_row(); 

                    // vars
                    $content = get_sub_field('content');
                    ?>

         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">

                    <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'gaeilge') !== false) { ?> <!--Check if url contains the word "items"  -->
                        <h2 class="fw-b c-blue mt-0">Ár bhFís</h2>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <h2 class="fw-b c-blue mt-0">Our Vision</h2>
                    <?php } ?>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <p class="c-blue mb-0"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
                        </div>  

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: which error do you have?

Comment: The ACF repeater doesn't display when I also have the PHP code included on my page. There isn't an error message of any kind. If I remove the PHP code the ACF does display. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: So don't display no one condition from IF?

Comment: All you are doing in that first if/else block, is assign different values to `$newsCat`. What is that variable used for, and where? _“as it doesn't display”_ - check what the actual HTML code created by your script looks like in that place. The output might be there, but not get shown due to nesting errors or similar issues in the HTML.

Comment: The first if/else block is used to display news articles on the homepage. It displays fine but seems to be interfering with the ACF php which doesn't display. ACF is not appearing in the HTML. I'm fairly new at php so i'm not 100% in figuring out these issues,

Comment: Should of noted that this is a multiesite so the php code is displaying new articles with different languages on each site.

Comment: What does "don't display no one condition from IF" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by just changing how News articles where added.

```
    <div class="row pt-4 pb-3"> 

            <?php
            // args
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'post'

            );
            // query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
            <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-5">
                        <div class="w-100 mb-2 px-2">
                           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="w-100" src="<?php $featimage = the_post_thumbnail_url('news-image'); ?>" alt=""></a>
                           <p class="text-muted mt-4 mb-2"><?php echo get_the_date('dS M, Y'); ?></p>
                           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <h3 class="c-blue"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

    </div>
```